# Mapping json data that have relation values inside

Tags: reactjs, json

I'm having difficulties about how I should approach rendering this JSON data that have relation values inside.

```
{
  "data":{
    "comments":[
      {
        "id":"1",
        "text":"Data 1"
      },
      {
        "id":"2",
        "parent_id" : "1"
        "text":"Data 2 with relation to Data 1",
      },
      {
        "id":"3",
        "text":"Data 3",
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

And it should look something like this in my head: [image]

Comment: We are going to need a lot more information than a drawing from your head. 

Can you rephrase the question with what you expect the output to be?

Comment: Im looking to make some sort of a comment section, and some comments have reply on them. I want to render that reply under comment that it was left on. That’s why I use parent_id to match comment and reply to that comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how this could be done:

```
const sortedComments = data.comments.sort((a, b) => a.parent_id - b.parent_id);

return (
  <div>
    {sortedComments.map(comment => {
      if (comment.parent_id) {
        return (
          <div key={comment.id}>
            <div>{comment.text}</div>
            <div>
              {sortedComments.map(childComment => {
                if (childComment.parent_id === comment.id) {
                  return (
                    <div key={childComment.id}>
                      <div>{childComment.text}</div>
                    </div>
                  );
                }
              })}
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      } else {
        return (
          <div key={comment.id}>
            <div>{comment.text}</div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    })}
  </div>
);
```